# Flutter Modal Bottom Sheet with Navigator does not pop as expected

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet, materialpageroute

I a working with [ModalBottomSheet](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) and I love the package. However I am encountering an issue when trying to navigate with in a ModalBottomSheet.

Here is a [ScreenVideo](https://gofile.io/d/SWLIAe) for a better understanding.

As you can see the View is presented as a ModalBottomSheet. But when popping it, it is not simply dismissing to the bottom but instead it is popping to some empty screen with a MaterialPage Pop animation.

I changed my code so I can push with a MaterialPageRoute-Animation inside that ModalBottomSheet. Before that everything was working as expected.

Here is my Page:

```
    class _AboutScreenState extends State<AboutScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: AppColors.primary,
      child: Navigator(
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context2) => Builder(
            builder: (context) => CupertinoPageScaffold(
                backgroundColor: AppColors.secondary,
                resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                child: SafeArea(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(sidePadding),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            IconButtonWithExpandedTouchTarget(
                              onTapped: () {
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              svgPath: 'assets/icons/down.svg',
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'About',
                          style: AppTextStyles.montserratH2SemiBold,
                        ),

                        ...

                        RoundedCornersTextButton(
                          title: 'Impressum',
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          textColor: AppColors.primary,
                          backgroundColor: AppColors.secondary,
                          borderColor: AppColors.primary,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I was simply following this [example](https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet/blob/master/example/lib/modals/modal_with_navigator.dart). What am I missing here? With the code above I can push inside the ModalSheet as expected with a MaterialPageRoute Animation but popping the first screen brings up the issue...

Let me know if you need any more info! Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried using `build`'s `BuildContext`? In the example, it uses `rootContext` during `pop`.

Comment: @rickimaru yes that was it! Thanks your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are popping with the wrong context. The example is popping with `rootContext`, which is from the top-most widget in the hierarchy. You are popping from with `context`, defined at your lowest builder in the hierarchy.

Comment: thanks! I didnt see that... It is working as expected now :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the incorrect context. rootContext, which is from the top-most widget in the hierarchy, is what makes the sample pop. You're popping from your lowest builder in the hierarchy, which is dictated by context.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).